# Getting stack error: 0 [main] stringL 1123 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to stringL.exe.stackdump

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, singly-linked-list, c-strings

I've defined a struct to represent strings and want to make a list from this string-structs. I've coded a function toString, which gets a char pointer and the result is such a string-struct. I've coded a function toList, which gets a pointer of char pointer, makes strings from these char pointers and concatenate these to a list of strings.

Now I want to use these, but I always get this stack error  `0 [main] stringL 1123 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to stringL.exe.stackdump`. Could the problem be the assignment with makro? Not even the debug output 0, 1, 2, 3 is printed. I'm thankful for some help.

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define EMPTYLIST NULL
#define ISEMPTY(l) ((l) == EMPTYLIST)
#define TAIL(l) ((l)->next)
#define HEAD(l) ((l)->str)

typedef struct {
    char *str;
    unsigned int len;
} String;

typedef struct ListNode *StringList;

struct ListNode {
    String str;
    StringList next;
};

String toString (char *cstr) {
    String res = {NULL, 0};
    res.str = malloc(sizeof(char));
    
    char *ptr = res.str;
    
    while(*cstr) {
        *ptr++ = *cstr++;
        res.str = realloc(res.str, sizeof(char) * (res.len +2));
        res.len++;
    }
    *ptr = '\0';
    return res;
}

StringList toList (char **cstrs, unsigned int sc){
    if(sc > 0) {
        StringList res = malloc(sizeof(*res));
        HEAD(res) = toString(*cstrs);
        TAIL(res) = toList(cstrs+1, sc+1);
    }
    return EMPTYLIST;
}

int main() {
    printf("0");
    char **strs = malloc(sizeof(**strs) *2);
    unsigned int i = 0;
    char *fst = "Der erste Text";
    char *snd = "Der zweite Text";

    printf("1");
    StringList res = toList(strs, 2);
    StringList lstPtr = res;

    strs[0] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 15);
    strs[1] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 16);
printf("2");
    while(*fst) {
        strs[0][i] = *fst++;
        i++;
    }
    printf("3");
    i = 0;
    while(*snd) {
        strs[1][i] = *snd++;
        i++;
    }
    
    printf("Liste: \n");
    
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        printf("Text %d: %s\n", i, HEAD(lstPtr++));
    }
    
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

After this statement

```
    res.str = realloc(res.str, sizeof(char) * (res.len +2));
```

the value stored in the pointer `res.str` can be changed. As a result the value stored in the pointer `ptr` after its increment

```
    *ptr++ = *cstr++;
```

can be invalid and does not point to a place in the reallocated memory.